# Fetching Data from 2 dictionary and placing the data in a class in respective class members

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, c#-4.0, json.net

i am having 2 dictionaries which is fetched from json and it looks like this

```
Dict1={"code":"iCode","Name":"EmpName","Number":"EmpNo"}

Dict2={"iCode":"12345","EmpName":"Messi","EmpNo":"4321"}
```

i need to customize/arrange these data's in a class

The `gen` class look like this:

```
public class gen
     {
        [DataMember]
        public string Code{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value{ get; set; }
     }
```

My output should look like this:

```
gen.Code="12345";
gen.Value="EmpName":"Messi"+"&&"+"EmpNo":"4321";
```

To be more specific only the iCode value "12345" must be in gen.Code and all other values must be in gen.Value.but cant guarantee that icode will always be in first position of `Dict2` it can be any where and also this iCode can vary with name like iReq,CodeNo...etc but Code from `Dict1`is unique.
How will be the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have PascalCase names for classes (`Gen`) and camelCase names for variables (`dict1`, `dict2`, `gen`).

> but cant guarantee that icode will always be in first position of
>   Dict2 it can be any where

Dictionary is not ordered type of collection.

```
var codeKey = dict1["code"];
var nameKey = dict1["Name"];
var numberKey = dict1["Number"];

var gen = new Gen {
    Code = dict2[codeKey],
    Value = $"{nameKey}:{dict2[nameKey]}&&{numberKey}:{dict2[numberKey]}"
};
```

Note that you can merge two dictionaries:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
   { "code", "iCode" }, 
   { "Name", "EmpName" }, 
   { "Number", "EmpNo" }
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
   { "iCode", "12345" },
   { "EmpName", "Messi" },
   { "EmpNo", "4321" }
};

var dict = dict1.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => dict2[kvp.Value]);
```

That will produce dictionary with following entries:

```
   { "code", "12345" }, 
   { "Name", "Messi" }, 
   { "Number", "4321" }
```